# Using Regex in TerraForm resource

Tags: regex, terraform0.12+

I'm using TerraForm to provision a Grafana environment. The setup is mostly complete, but I'm wrestling with a final bit. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
resource "grafana_folder" "folder" {
 for_each = toset(var.grafana_folders)
 title = each.key
}

resource "grafana_dashboard" "dashboards" {
  for_each    = fileset(path.module, "../dashboards/*.json")
  config_json = file("${path.module}/${each.key}")
  folder = grafana_folder.folder[regex("/^[^_]*_([^_]*)_/", "${each.key}")[0]].id
}
```

I create a set of folders (based on a variable list). I then create a set of dashboards based on files in a folder. These files have a name-prefix that identifies in which folder they should go.

For example: *db_Folder1_34ne34A* <-- this dashboard should go in Folder1

When I test this code and hard-code the name of one of the folders, as follows:

```
  folder = grafana_folder.folder["Folder1"].id
```

Things work fine. All dashboards are placed in that folder.

The last step is to extract the folder-identifier from *each.key* and use that instead of the hardcoded value. But I can't seem to get the regex to work. The regex I'm using looks like it should work:

https://regex101.com/r/D4NqG5/1

It gives the Group (not the Match), but according to the TerraForm documentation that should give me a list (of one element, in this case), that I should be able to grab with [0].
But I get the following error:
*Call to function "regex" failed: pattern did not match any part of the given string.*

I've tried other regex variations, but in many cases these use what amounts to escape characters in TerraForm, which gives me a whole different range of errors, or use lookAhead, which is not supported by Go.

Anyone a bit more familiar with using regex in TerraForm that can give me a push in the right direction?

** EDIT **

I've identified it's down to getting the captureGroup from the RegEx.

If I do the following (added a try to be safe):

```
folder = try(grafana_folder.folder[regex("Folder1|Folder2", "${each.key}")].id, 0)
```

it works fine. The difference is that this regex returns a correct *Match* where the previous one returns a correct *captureGroup*. TerraForm returns the latter in the form of a list, that I try to get the first index from using [0] or [*][0] without success.

Of course this is a very crude regex. So my problem is down to one of two things:

1. A regex that returns a correct *match* for 'anything between db_ and _ (looking for one right now)
2. A way to get the first captureGroup returned by the Regex

Comment: I don't know terraform, but there is a [replace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/replace.html) function that can take a regex. Perhaps you could use `^db_([^_]+)_\S*` and replace with group 1 using `$1` See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ls2vIb/1)

Comment: From what I read about [regex](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/regex.html) is that if you have a unnamed capture group, you get a list of the captured substrings. [This page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/element.html) has some info about how to get a single element from a list.